# Why doesn't rsync keep my user and groups even with the -o / -g option?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

On the client side:

```
rsync -x -r -t -v -o "nobody" -g "nogroup" --progress --delete -u --partial -s -e ssh /home/john/Calibre\ Library root@192.168.0.21:/media/Book
```

On the server side:

```
clementine:/c/media/Book# ls -la
total 20
drwxrwxrwt   3 nobody nogroup  4096 Jul  1 20:34 .
drwxrwxrwt  13 nobody nogroup  4096 Jul  1 19:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x 246 backup users   12288 Jun 30 17:37 Calibre Library
```

I have no idea why it changes the user and group and doesn't assign to the right one.
Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I'm starting to think that your problem [might be related to the UID/GID being different on your machines](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/45856-rsync-preserve-owner-group-different-uid-gid.html).

A user [on this site](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/rsync-not-preserving-owner-and-group-668364/) explains the following:

> You don't have the usernames in /etc/passwd on the new server and
>   that's why the owner/group names are not seen on the files you copied
>   over.
>
> Just copy over the appropriate entries in /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow,
>   and /etc/group from the old server to the new one and that should be
>   it.

Does that make sense? In the comments I mentioned using the "stat" command on certain files/folders both on the client and server. Part of the output of stat will display the UID and GID. This may help in determining differences between the client and server.

Original Answer:

I see that you have "root@192.168.0.21", but go ahead and make sure to add the "--super" option to your command.

```
rsync -x -r -t -v -o "nobody" -g "nogroup" --super --progress --delete -u --partial -s -e ssh /home/john/Calibre\ Library root@192.168.0.21:/media/Boo
```

[Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> -o, --owner
>   This option causes rsync to set the owner of the destination file to be the same as the source file, but only if the
>   receiving rsync is being run as the super-user (see also the --super
>   and --fake-super options). Without this option, the owner of new
>   and/or transferred files are set to the invoking user on the receiving
>   side.

Comment: It still don't work.  :-(

It use  "backup" and "users" instead of "nobody" and "nogroup".

I don't understand....

Comment: ➜  ~  rsync -x -r -t -v -o "nobody" -g "nogroup" --super --progress --delete -u --partial -s -e ssh /home/zobi8225/Calibre\ Library root@192.168.0.21:/c/media/Book      
[...]

rsync: link_stat "/home/zobi8225/nobody" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/zobi8225/nogroup" failed: No such file or directory (2)
Calibre Library/

[..]

Comment: Can you paste the output to the following commands?

On the client side:
stat "/home/john/Calibre\ Library"

On the server side:
stat "/c/media/Book"

Comment: Client side : http://pastebin.com/JA8d5BMf

Server side : http://pastebin.com/JD3F0r95

Thanks

Comment: That looks like output from your rsync commands? Can you instead post output for the stat commands as listed above?

Comment: @zobi8225 Any luck with your problem? Don't forget the green check mark if the answer qualifies. Thanks!